# CURL returned response array not well formatted PHP

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I'm trying to get each element from http headers. However the returned array from curl have is not fomatted well

```
<?php
$url = "http://www.wdudes.com/";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $curl, array(
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url ) );
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $headers = explode( "\n", $response);
    print_r($headers);
?>
```

The output obtained is

```
Array ( 
[0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
[1] => Date: Fri, 29 Apr 2016 10:35:20 GMT 
[2] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
[3] => Connection: close 
)
```

I want array to formatted as:

```
Array ( 
[0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
[Date] => Fri, 29 Apr 2016 10:35:20 GMT 
[Content-Type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8 
[Connection] => close 
)
```

Comment: Do not explode with new line than !

Comment: Use `foreach`, `explode` and `trim`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually use this way:

```
<?php
    $headers = array(
      "HTTP/1.1 200 OK ",
      "Date: Fri, 29 Apr 2016 10:35:20 GMT ",
      "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 ",
      "Connection: close"
    );
    $better = array();
    foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
      if ($key == 0)
        $better[] = $value;
      else {
        $current = explode(":", $value, 2);
        $better[trim($current[0])] = trim($current[1]);
      }
    }
```

**Output:** [Demo](http://ideone.com/8NgwVb)

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
    [Date] => Fri, 29 Apr 2016 10:35:20 GMT
    [Content-Type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [Connection] => close
)
```

This is the basic logic. If there's any better and more performant way to do, they are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This method is similar to Praveen's answer but ensure's that any answers with additional colons in will be handled.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($output); $i++){

    //If array item contains ": "
    if(strpos($output[$i], ': ') !== false){

        //New key is text before the colon
        $newKey = substr($output[$i], 0, strpos($output[$i], ': '));

        //New val is text after the colon
        $newVal = substr($output[$i], strpos($output[$i], ': ')+1, strlen($output[$i]));

        //Remove item from existing array
        $output[$i] = "";       

        //Write item to array using new key and value
        $output[$newKey] = $newVal;
    }
}
```

You can optionally remove the "Remove item from existing array" line if not required.

You can then display the results using print_r(array_filter($output));

Results are as follows:

```
Original Array
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Date: Fri, 29 Apr 2016 10:35:20 GMT
    [2] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [3] => Connection: close
)


New Array:
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    [Date] =>  Fri, 29 Apr 2016 10:35:20 GMT
    [Content-Type] =>  text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [Connection] =>  close
)


Filtered Array:
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [Date] =>  Fri, 29 Apr 2016 10:35:20 GMT
    [Content-Type] =>  text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [Connection] =>  close
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snap of code :

```
$newArray = array();

foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {

if(preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]*[^:]*/',$value) and $key != 0){
 preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]*[^:]*/',$value, $newKey);
$newKey = $newKey[0];
$newArray[$newKey] = trim(str_replace($newKey.':','',$value));
 }else{
$newKey = 0;
    $newArray[0] = $value;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

- Use a `$flag` variable to skip the first element i.e `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`
- Iterate through the array using `foreach` loop, and in each iteration use `explode()` function to get the new (key, value) pair and use the new key to push the new value at the appropriate position in the array
- Finally, unset the old element using the old key of the array

So your code should be like this:

```
// Suppose $headers is your original array

$flag = true;
foreach($headers as $key => $value){
    if($flag){
        $flag = false;
        continue;
    }
    if(strlen(trim($value))){
        $component = explode(": ", $value);
        $headers[$component[0]] = $component[1];
        unset($headers[$key]);
    }else{
        unset($headers[$key]);
    }
}

// display $headers array
var_dump($headers);
```